# Equation of a sequence of a pyramid of glasses. Trying to find the sequence equations for the fill rates and number of pours.

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is my problem:

[image]

I am trying to find equations for the sequences in order to calculate the fill rate of a glass and how many pours until it starts to be filled.

For example (tower of the fill rates):

```
    1                     (1)
    2                 (1/2) (1/2)
    3             (1/4)  (2/4)  (1/4)
    4         (1/8)  (3/8)  (3/8)  (1/8)
    5     (1/16) (4/16) (6/16) (4/16) (1/16)
    6 (1/32) (5/32) (10/32)(10/32) (5/32) (1/32)
```

This is what the fill rate of each glass would look like. (When the top glass is full, 1/2 of a pour goes into the right and 1/2 goes into the left, etc.)
I am trying to find an equation for the rates. The equation for the denominator is simple: $(n-1)^2$, but I am struggling to find the equations for the numerators. The pyramid is mirrored so we can ignore the right side, making the series for the numerators:

```
    1| 1
    2| 1
    3| 1 2
    4| 1 3
    5| 1 4 6
    6| 1 5 10
    7| 1 6 15 20
    8| 1 7 21 35
    9| 1 8 28 56 70
   10| 1 9 36 84 126
```

I can see the patterns in the columns, so I started to write equations for each column:

Column 1: $1$

Column 2: $n-1$

Column 3: $1/2(n-2)^2+1/2(n-2)$

I am struggling to write equations for columns 4+ as I can't find much information on cubic and quartic series. I would also need to combine all of these into one equation. Is this the right idea for how to simulate this with equations? My end goal is to be able to calculate how much liquid is in a glass given a number of pours with only equations.

Edit:
I got an equation for the rates:
$$(n,k)=\frac{\frac{n}{k-1}∗\frac{n+1−k}{k}}{{2}^{n-1}}$$

Now I am trying to get an equation for the time each glass starts to be filled:

```
                0
            1       1
        3       3       3
    7       5       5       7
15    23/3     23/3    23/3   15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Denominator** is $2^{n-1}$ , that is $1,2,4,8,16,\cdots$ Powers of $2$.

The **Numerator** is Pascals triangle , Binomial Expansion terms , Permutations & Combinations.
**Quick Summary :  the rows are made by adding 2 consecutive elements of the previous row.**
Eg row 3 is $1,2,1$.
Hence row 4 will be $0+1=1,1+2=3,2+1=3,1+0=1$ (we assume there is a Zero at the Start & End)
Now row 5 will be $0+1=1,1+3=4,3+3=6,3+1=4,1+0=1$ (we always assume there is a Zero at the Start & End)
Then row 6 will be $0+1=1,1+4=5,4+6=10,6+4=10,4+1=5,1+0=1$.
This is matching the Numbers you have listed.

There are lots of online references for getting the formula for that , in terms of factorial , hence I will not elaborate it more.
Let me know if you still want the formula.

Check out :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: Thank you, do you think it would be possible to write an equation of the triangle without using summation or recursion? I am trying to convert this to code and I am wondering if I can do it without loops or recursion.

Comment: I think I have something: $(n, k) = n/(k-1)*(n+1-k)/k$ that seems to work although it breaks down for the second half of the triangle.

Comment: The above equation works perfectly, now I am trying to write an equation for how many pours it takes for a glass to start being filled. Based on this manually constructed pyramid (Pyramid is in the main post) I don't think it is possible to write an equation for when glasses start to be filled. Because of the weird fractions you get glasses sometimes start to get poured midway through a pour which results in some crazy sequences that don't seem predictable.